# zgrep to search pattern in log

Tags: linux, grep

I have a log file, in this pattern:

```
IP - - [date] "command" response time
```

I want to search in the log the lines which contains the ip:`68.45.3.1` and part of the command: `"/api/con"`

So this is a correct result:

```
68.45.3.1 - - [05/Nov/2015:03:48:25 -0500] "GET /5.0/api/con/1" 20:01
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
zgrep "^68.45.3.1.*\/api\/con" access.log.*.gz
```

assuming of course that your files are something like `access.log.10.gz` etc. (change the name of the file if this isn't the case).